# Ensure application continues running on server after RDP is disconnected

Tags: windows-server-2019, application, scheduler

I have an application that runs on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter. This application is run by a specific user log-on. The user must remain logged in to Windows for the application to continue running.

When the account logs off the RDP session, the application closes after some time. When the account logs on again with RDP, it goes through the entire process of applying group policies and so on.

**How do I prevent this from happening?**

I want this application to run continuously, 24/7. I already have a Scheduler Task that checks periodically and if the application has crashed, restarts it.

**I cannot convert this to a service because the application must run in an interactive session.**

Any advice is appreciated!

Edited to Add: I am not logging out. I just disconnect the RDP. I also have set the machine to not log out after inactivity (the parameter is set to "Not Defined")

Comment: There is a difference between "logging out" and "disconnecting" from RDP. If you close your RDP session, you may get a warning "Processes will continue to run"; that's what you want. It sounds to me like you are disconnecting and then your system is timing out on inactivity and automatically logging you out...

Comment: @tsc_chazz Thanks for the answer. I do get this warning and I was expecting the process to continue running, when I disconnect the RDP but it does not seem to keep working. I also updated the machine inactivity limit to 0 to make sure it does not log out the user. It still seems to do so. Anything else I should look at?

Comment: Active Directory Users and Computers, user Properties, Sessions tab, make sure that `End a disconnected session` is set to Never. I'd also set `Active session limit` and `Idle session limit` to Never; `When session limit is reached or connection is broken` set `Disconnect`, and I'd likely enable `Allow reconnection: From any client`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this!

Comment: `I am not logging out`. The account is being logged off. Otherwise, it would not go through the **logon** process that you described "it goes through the entire process of applying group policies and so on.". 100% logged off.

Comment: @GregAskew, I understand that this is what is happening, however, I do not actually log out. As I mentioned in my reply to tsc_chazz, I see the warning that about applications continuing to run. I assume there's some sort of policy that logs off the user automatically and I need to find out why (since I've specifically set Log out after inactivity to "Not Defined")

Comment: `I do not actually log out.` it doesn't matter. The session first disconnects for a configured amount of time, then logs off after a configured amount of time. This applies to every Windows system in existence since 2000, about 23 years.

Comment: regardless I would suggest that you take a look at the nssm service manager, it is also possible to run interactive programs as a windows service

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad practice to run an application process in an RDP session. Either try to run it as a windows service or using task scheduler.

You can create custom windows services using PowerShell.